# Swift collection types

Tags: swift, collections

I am learning swift and I was reading a source code for one app but I was note able to understand this line of code

```
static var model: STFCellModelCollection<AnyObject,OPPCollectionViewCell>?
```

I re-read the collection types section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) but still don't understand this declaration Is it a set, an array, a dictionary ... ?

Comment: You should find the declaration of this STFCellModelCollection class in your source code and see it's structure. It's not a class from native framework.

Comment: You may want to read about *generics* in the Swift reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is custom class, written by project author or declared in some used in it library. You can use *option+click* and *command+click* on `STFCellModelCollection`, and, simply, global project search to find some information about it